Sound triggers when particles collide with plane/object
I'm looking for a way how to activate a sound when a particle collides with another object in Blender.
In this case, I would like to know how to do this with a particle and a plane.
The scene is something like this


I'm using two planes: one as a particle emitter, which is being rendered as raindrops; and another as a collider with a dynamic paint modifier (canvas). The raindrops fall one by one at different intervals. I want a sound to be played when each raindrop hits the collider. The particle emitter and the X/Y/Z axes are controlled by OSC via Touchdesigner. I'm using JPfeP/AddRoutes to communicate between the softwares. I want to send a trigger from Blender to Touchdesigner when each particle hits the ground to play a sample. Alternatively the sound can also be played inside blender.
The OSC message struture for Touchdesigner, that can be sent via a plugin, or by script must have:
IP Address: of the machine running Touchdesigner.
Port Number: The port number which is listening
Address Pattern: A string that identifies the specific action or event, e.g. "/collision".
Arguments: for triggering a sound, this might simply be a numeric value (e.g. 1 or 0) or a string indicating the event.
Example of OSC Message
Address Pattern: "/collision"
Argument: 1 (indicating a collision event)

I'm using two planes: one as a particle emitter, which is being rendered as raindrops; and another as a collider with a dynamic paint modifier (canvas).
The raindrops fall one by one at different intervals. I want a sound to be played when each raindrop hits the collider.
The particle emitter and the X/Y/Z axes are controlled by OSC via Touchdesigner. I'm using JPfeP/AddRoutes to communicate between the softwares.
I want to send a trigger from Blender to Touchdesigner when each particle hits the ground to play a sample.
Please let me know if more information is needed.
Thanks.

Please edit your question and add your comment into that rather than adding extra information as a comment which people might not see. Also we can't really help with sending triggers to external software as we have no idea what "Touchdesigner" might be expecting!

The sound can also be triggered in blender, touchdesigner is only an option. Is the same osc data blender expects.
